# How to get name of elements collected with ElementIsElementType

Tags: ironpython, revit-api

I can  get all the column types (used and unused) in the revit model with following snippet

```
target_category = DB.BuiltInCategory.OST_StructuralColumns
elements_type = DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc)\
        .OfCategory(target_category)\
        .WhereElementIsElementType()\
        .ToElements()
```

How to get name of contents in elements_type. I couldnot find any property like `.Name` which retrieves element type name.

Answer (score 1):

[FamilySymbol.Name](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/1198805b-fdbf-54bf-64d3-90dbd01b4c5f.htm) and [Element.Name](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/e372092e-ff47-71c2-1272-50ab08e5a41d.htm).

Comment: `FamilySymbol.Name` is for setting the name of FamilySymbol, which  i had used to successfully rename types. What i need is to Get the name of symbol. When i try `element_type[0].Name` i get `Attribute error` saying it doesnot have an attribute `Name`